# Onclicking Add student button in home_v.php page, open another view page user_v.php

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter-3

```
<html>
<head><head>
<title>Home Page</title>
<body>
<style>
.looks
{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<center><h1>Welcome Students!</h1><br><br></center>
<span style="float: right;">
<a href="<?php echo site_url().'/user_c/logout' ?>">Logout</a>      
</span>
<h2>List of Students in system are : </h2>
<div id="list">
<table class='looks'>
<tr><th>Student Name</th>
<th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
<?php
    foreach ($list->result() as $row)
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='width:30%'>".$row->name."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' value='Add Student' style='float:left' 
    onclick="site_url().'/user_c/add'"></td>";
    echo '<td><input type="submit" value="Update Student" 
    style="float:left"></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="submit" value="Delete Student" 
    style="float:left"></td>';
    echo "</tr>";      
    }
?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Parse Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXmXn.png)

The foreach loop is executed and the values of student are displayed on the 
 home_v.php page. Besides the names of these students, I have added a button 
 (Add Student).On clicking this button I want to open another view page 
 user_v.php, for which I have used onclick tag in the button. But it is not 
 working and I get the error attached below. Kindly help as what is the mistake 
 I am making.

```
    //controller
    function add()
    {
        $this->load->view('user_v');
    }
```

Comment: you tagged it javascript where is the js file like this function setUpdateAction() {
document.frmUser.action = "edit_user.php";
document.frmUser.submit();
}
function setDeleteAction() {
document.frmUser.action = "delete_user.php";
document.frmUser.submit();
}

Comment: I am sorry, it was added by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making mistake in concatenating PHP and HTML data. 
And to make it work on the click do following changes:

```
echo "<td><input type='submit' value='Add Student' style='float:left' 
onclick=window.location='". site_url("user_c/add")."'></td>";
```

Comment: I executed the above answer, but on clicking the Add Student button, no action is taking place. Kindly help as what is the issue.